# How can I exit a program in the OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell

What is a quick way to exit a program in the OSX terminal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

press <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in your keyboard.

and in some man-page and vim editor write ***`:q`*** and  press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Try pressing Ctrl-c.

Answer (score 1):

As they pointed out, you can press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in almost any terminal application

OR

In OS X, you can additionally press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>